# How to copy a file to clipboard by VBA?

Tags: vba, file, copy, clipboard

I like to copy an excel file to clipboard by VBA, so that I can paste the excel file to some other places. I found the below VBA codes on the internet. But the codes seems not working, the Excel file (contain the VBA code) shut down automatically after running the codes. Can some one advise? Thanks.

```
Option Explicit

' Required data structures
Private Type POINTAPI
x As Long
y As Long
End Type

' Clipboard Manager Functions
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare  PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long

' Other required Win32 APIs
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "DragQueryFileA" (ByVal hDrop As Long, ByVal UINT As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal ch As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryPoint Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal hDrop As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMem Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

' Predefined Clipboard Formats
Private Const CF_TEXT = 1
Private Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Private Const CF_METAFILEPICT = 3
Private Const CF_SYLK = 4
Private Const CF_DIF = 5
Private Const CF_TIFF = 6
Private Const CF_OEMTEXT = 7
Private Const CF_DIB = 8
Private Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Private Const CF_PENDATA = 10
Private Const CF_RIFF = 11
Private Const CF_WAVE = 12
Private Const CF_UNICODETEXT = 13
Private Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
Private Const CF_HDROP = 15
Private Const CF_LOCALE = 16
Private Const CF_MAX = 17

' New shell-oriented clipboard formats
Private Const CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST As String = "Shell IDList Array"
Private Const CFSTR_SHELLIDLISTOFFSET As String = "Shell Object Offsets"
Private Const CFSTR_NETRESOURCES As String = "Net Resource"
Private Const CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR As String = "FileGroupDescriptor"
Private Const CFSTR_FILECONTENTS As String = "FileContents"
Private Const CFSTR_FILENAME As String = "FileName"
Private Const CFSTR_PRINTERGROUP As String = "PrinterFriendlyName"
Private Const CFSTR_FILENAMEMAP As String = "FileNameMap"

' Global Memory Flags
Private Const GMEM_FIXED = &H0
Private Const GMEM_MOVEABLE = &H2
Private Const GMEM_NOCOMPACT = &H10
Private Const GMEM_NODISCARD = &H20
Private Const GMEM_ZEROINIT = &H40
Private Const GMEM_MODIFY = &H80
Private Const GMEM_DISCARDABLE = &H100
Private Const GMEM_NOT_BANKED = &H1000
Private Const GMEM_SHARE = &H2000
Private Const GMEM_DDESHARE = &H2000
Private Const GMEM_NOTIFY = &H4000
Private Const GMEM_LOWER = GMEM_NOT_BANKED
Private Const GMEM_VALID_FLAGS = &H7F72
Private Const GMEM_INVALID_HANDLE = &H8000
Private Const GHND = (GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)
Private Const GPTR = (GMEM_FIXED Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)

Private Type DROPFILES
pFiles As Long
pt As POINTAPI
fNC As Long
fWide As Long
End Type


Public Function ClipboardCopyFiles(Files() As String) As Boolean

Dim data As String
Dim df As DROPFILES
Dim hGlobal As Long
Dim lpGlobal As Long
Dim i As Long

' Open and clear existing crud off clipboard.
If OpenClipboard(0&) Then
Call EmptyClipboard

' Build double-null terminated list of files.
For i = LBound(Files) To UBound(Files)
data = data & Files(i) & vbNullChar
Next
data = data & vbNullChar

' Allocate and get pointer to global memory,
' then copy file list to it.
hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(df) + Len(data))
If hGlobal Then
lpGlobal = GlobalLock(hGlobal)

' Build DROPFILES structure in global memory.
df.pFiles = Len(df)
Call CopyMem(ByVal lpGlobal, df, Len(df))
Call CopyMem(ByVal (lpGlobal + Len(df)), ByVal data, Len(data))
Call GlobalUnlock(hGlobal)

' Copy data to clipboard, and return success.
If SetClipboardData(CF_HDROP, hGlobal) Then
ClipboardCopyFiles = True
End If
End If

' Clean up
Call CloseClipboard
End If

End Function

Public Function ClipboardPasteFiles(Files() As String) As Long

Dim hDrop As Long
Dim nFiles As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim desc As String
Dim filename As String
Dim pt As POINTAPI
Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

' Insure desired format is there, and open clipboard.
If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_HDROP) Then
If OpenClipboard(0&) Then

' Get handle to Dropped Filelist data, and number of files.
hDrop = GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP)
nFiles = DragQueryFile(hDrop, -1&, "", 0)

' Allocate space for return and working variables.
ReDim Files(0 To nFiles - 1) As String
filename = Space(MAX_PATH)

' Retrieve each filename in Dropped Filelist.
For i = 0 To nFiles - 1
Call DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, filename, Len(filename))
Files(i) = TrimNull(filename)
Next

' Clean up
Call CloseClipboard
End If

' Assign return value equal to number of files dropped.
ClipboardPasteFiles = nFiles
End If

End Function

Private Function TrimNull(ByVal sTmp As String) As String

Dim nNul As Long

'
' Truncate input sTmpg at first Null.
' If no Nulls, perform ordinary Trim.
'
nNul = InStr(sTmp, vbNullChar)
Select Case nNul
Case Is > 1
TrimNull = Left(sTmp, nNul - 1)
Case 1
TrimNull = ""
Case 0
TrimNull = Trim(sTmp)
End Select

Sub maaa()

'i = "c:\" & ActiveDocument.Name
'ActiveDocument.SaveAs i
Dim afile(0) As String

afile(0) = "c:\070206.excel" 'The file actually exists
MsgBox ClipboardCopyFiles(afile)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would do a proper Win API declaration

```
#If VBA7 Then
    ' Clipboard Manager Functions
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    
    ' Other required Win32 APIs
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal HDROP As LongPtr, ByVal UINT As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal ch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryPoint Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal HDROP As LongPtr, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMem Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
#Else
    ' Clipboard Manager Functions
    Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    
    ' Other required Win32 APIs
    Private Declare Function DragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal HDROP As Long, ByVal UINT As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal ch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function DragQueryPoint Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal HDROP As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Sub CopyMem Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#End If
```

Keep in mind that you would need for example

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Dim hGlobal As LongPtr
    Dim lpGlobal As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim hGlobal As Long
    Dim lpGlobal As Long
#End If
```

whenever you declare variables (that WIN API 'uses') in your functions/subs. This is needed just so it works on versions prior to MS Office 2010.

If you are sure that your code will be used on version 2010+, you can drop everything after `#Else` or drop conditional compilation altogether and just use declarations inside `VBA7`. `LongPtr` is 32/64 bit.

In your code you need to `End Function` `TrimNull` as well.

Also if you plan on using WIN API extensively you should check https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9970

Answer (score 0):

i tried repeately and with no success to make this work for MS Excell 2019. But i found this. that will work just fine:

```
Function CopyFileToClipboard(filePath As String, verb As String) As Integer
    Dim shell As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Dim dataObj As Object

    Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set file = shell.Namespace("").ParseName(filePath)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If file Is Nothing Then
        CopyFileToClipboard = 0
    Else
        file.InvokeVerb (verb)
        CopyFileToClipboard = 1
    End If
End Function
```

Hope to be helpfull.