# How to convert 32-bit Access code VBA code to run on 64-bit Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, 32bit-64bit

```
Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIndex As Long, _
    ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" _
    (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, _
     ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal msg As Long, _
     ByVal wParam As Long, _
     ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
```

not sure what to try-I have a form built in access - the buttons to print and duplicate I believe are causing this error

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162062/how-to-copy-a-file-to-clipboard-by-vba

Comment: https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=windows-api-declaration-vba-64-bit